# Momentjs showing same date for all timezones

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, momentjs

I am trying to convert the DateTime by the user's browser using momentjs.

What is happening here:

```js
let timezone = moment.tz.guess();
console.log('timezone:', timezone);
let iso_date = moment('06-04-2020 12:22:05 PM', 'MM-D-YYYY hh:mm:ss A').toISOString();
console.log('iso_date:', iso_date)
console.log('from timezone:', moment(iso_date).tz(timezone).format('lll'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.31/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

I would like to convert the datetime as per user's browser. But no matter what I try, I am getting the same datetime without the change. How do I get different datestimes for different timezones?

`Inputted date: 06-04-2020 12:22:05 PM', 'MM-D-YYYY hh:mm:ss A`
`Inputted timezone: America/Los_Angeles`
`Expected Output: Jun 4, 2020 12:22 PM`

[image: Pacific Time]

`Inputted date: 06-04-2020 12:22:05 PM', 'MM-D-YYYY hh:mm:ss A`
`Inputted timezone: Asia/Calcutta`
`Expected Output: Jun 5, 2020 12:52 AM`

[image: IST]

Comment: @Phil, I have fixed that

Comment: For you (in `America/New_York`), what is the value reported above for `iso_string`?

Comment: @Phil, that is correct

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. When you run the above Stack Snippet, what is reported on the second line, ie `iso_date: ?????`

Comment: @Phil, iso_date: 2020-06-04T06:52:05.000Z

Comment: RIght, so what exactly is your question? You are comparing two different dates, `2020-06-04T06:52:05.000Z` and `2020-06-04T19:22:05.000Z` so naturally, the results would be different

Comment: @Phil, I just realized that. Is there a way to convert the time as per the user's timezone? I don't think that is happening

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. When you parse `"06-04-2020 12:22:05 PM"`, that is treated as a local time. JavaScript ISO dates are always represented in UTC (that's what the `Z` means) but it's still the same point in time. As you can see in the last line of your console output, the time is always displayed as Jun 4, 12:22 PM which is the same date string you parsed

Comment: @Phil, I want to get `06-04-2020 12:22:05 PM` in various timezones

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking or what you're trying to do. I suggest you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62205705/edit) and write out in plain words, exactly what you're wanting to happen with examples of input values and expected outputs.

Comment: @Phil, I have edited it. Please help

Comment: @Phil, I have added that too

Comment: @Phil, I have added that as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what is going on.

```
let iso_date = moment('06-04-2020 12:22:05 PM', 'MM-D-YYYY hh:mm:ss A').toISOString();
```

Creates a date from '06-04-2020 12:22:05 PM', treating the values as local, then returns an ISO 8601 string for the UTC version of that date, e.g. 2020-06-04T06:52:05Z.

```
console.log('from var:', moment(iso_date).tz(timezone).format('lll'));
```

Takes the ISO formatted string and parses it as UTC, then creates a timestamp for the local timezone. So it **should** produce the same date and time as the original timestamp.

All the code does is parse a timestamp as local, generate an equivalent UTC timestamp, then reverse the process by converting the UTC timestamp to a local timestamp.

> How do I get different datestimes for different timezones?

Use a different location for parsing and formatting. If you use the same location for both, or locations with the same offset, then you'll get the same date and time back. It's exactly the same as doing:

```js
let s = 'Fri Jun 05 2020 10:41:25';
let d = new Date(s);
let utc = d.toISOString();
console.log(
  'Started with : ' + s +
  '\nConverted to : ' + utc +  
  '\nBack to local: ' + new Date(utc).toString()
);
```